# I'm trying to find a way to log my current SSID to a document

Tags: bash

~ I'm looking for a way to find the current SSID and log this to a document. ~

I'm totally new to writing for the terminal so I'm already sorry for asking any dumb questions. Here's the thing: I'm looking for a way to find my current SSID and log this to a document (eventually it needs to be put into a Google Spreadsheet).

Preferable it will work like this: I start my mac, the script runs automatically and checks the current SSID. If it's new it logs it to the document. If it's been connected with this SSID before it won't do anything. Any help would be highly appreciated.

After lots of Googling I could only find this:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | awk '/ SSID/ {print substr($0, index($0, $2))}'
```

which does give me the current SSID...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if MAC have this, in ubuntu/linux world, you can try to use command `iwgetid -r` to see if it works